# How can I read a file from a node module?

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

In a naive implementation of `mymodule`, I did the following

`const file = fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/dependent_module/file.txt')`

However, when I include `mymodule` in `project`, the file read no longer works since the location of `dependent_module` has moved.

How can I read a file from a node module, such that I don't have to worry about *where* that node module is located?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `require.resolve('module')` then include that in the file path of the file you'd like to read